# Solucionar el error de Multidex en Eclipse sin el archivo build.gradle

Tags: java, android

Me da el error de "Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536".

La cuestión es que no tengo archivo `buid.gradle` en mi aplicación.
**Mi proyecto lo realice con Eclipse.**

¿Hay alguna solución? o ¿meter código en otro archivo de eclipse?

Comment: Lo puedes agregar desde una clase `Application` y lo llames en el `Manifest`

Comment: Hola, ¿cómo? podrías ponerme los pasos... por favor... gracias

Comment: No realices cambios, simplemente Importa el proyecto.

Answer (score 1):

si estas realizando un proyecto en android lo mas aconsejable como dice @jorsesys
1.- Instala android studio que es el IDE oficial para desarrollo en android
2.- Exportas tu proyecto de eclipse
3.- Importas el proyecto de eclipse a android

Se que, al inicio puede ser tedioso, pero creeme Android studio, esta realmente orientado para el desarrollo en android incluyendo que te facilita muchas cosas

saludos
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?hl=es-419

Answer (score 0):

Para esto, si tienes un proyecto realizado en eclipse, tienes que **importar tu proyecto** (no abrirlo), esto mediante la secuencia:

`File` > `New` > `Import Project` y selecciona el folder con tu proyecto realizado en Eclipse.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto creara los archivos necesarios para funcionar con Android Studio, incluso los `build.gradle`.

Comment: Hola, no acabo de entender... mi projecto ya esta hecho con eclipse...

Comment: Ok entonces dentro de Android Studio ve a File > New > Import Project y selecciona el folder con tu proyecto realizado en Eclipse.